# .Net Core 3.1 using the ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_USBHub") on MacOS application

Tags: .net-core

I need to get a list of all connected USB devices to a MacOS.
For Windows 32 bit system I do this:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_USBHub");
```

From what object do I have to query to get all the connected USB devices on a MacOS?

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM <<???>>");
```

Thanks

Comment: Try with "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity'";

Comment: @Sha, thanks for your quick response. I think I have to find an other solution to get the connected USB devices to a MacOS... I got the error: System.Management currently is only supported for Windows desktop applications. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It has been a while since I worked this MacOs I must confess but please see this snippet here: https://codeblog.vurdalakov.net/2018/02/howto-detect-usb-device-attachdetach-on.html